# Ubuntu bash –eq: binary operator expected - nested for loop

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to make Linux bash for my study homework and I think everything is fine(checked many resources), but still error is showing up (**–eq: binary operator expected** ). What's wrong in my example?

```
for (( i=1; i <= 3; i++)) ### Outer for loop ###
do
for (( j=1; j <= 3; j++)) ### Inner for loop ###
do
    tot=$(expr $i + $j)
    echo „tot value: $tot”
    tmp=$(expr $tot % 2)
    echo „tmp value: $tmp”
    if [ $tmp –eq 0 ]; then
        echo –e –n „\033[47m ”
    else
        echo –e –n „\033[40m”
    fi
done
echo –e –n „\033[40m” #### set back background colour to black
echo „” #### print the new line ####
done
```

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of starting a sub shell and calling `expr`, use the built-in arithmetic expansion in `bash` like: `(( tot = i + j ))`

Comment: Consider checking https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong character in `–eq`. It should be a minus (`-`), not a hyphen (`–`). The same goes for the hyphen you use on the `echo` lines.

Also consider using `bash`'s built-in arithmetic expansion instead of `expr` and `test`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i <= 3; i++)) ### Outer for loop ###
do
    for (( j=1; j <= 3; j++)) ### Inner for loop ###
    do
        (( tot = i + j ))
        echo "tot value: $tot"
        (( tmp = tot % 2 ))
        echo "tmp value: $tmp"

        if (( tmp == 0 )); then
            echo -e -n "\033[47m "
        else
            echo -e -n "\033[40m"
        fi
    done
    echo -e "\033[40m" #### set back background colour to black
done
```